# Change default radio button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, onload

I have a wordpress site with a plugin that gives me 2 radio buttons. These are Yes and No. Because Yes has a higher value than No the plugin chooses No as default.
For visitors to my website, Yes would be the most common answer. That's why I'm looking for some code that chooses the other radio button after the page is loaded. 
After googling, copying and pasting I came up with this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var $radios = $('input:radio[name=vraag]');
                $radios.filter('[value=Yes]').attr('checked', true);
            });
        </script>
```

I've put this in my wordpress template but it's not doing anything. I don't know anything about jquery or javascript, I only know a bit of basic HTML so I desperately need some guidance. Any one who can point me in the right direction please??

Comment: And the rendered HTML would be..?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for default select option in **document.ready function**

```
$("input:radio[value='PM']").attr("checked","checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery you could do this.

HTML

```
<input type='radio' name='type' class='radio-buttons' id='yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' name='type' class='radio-buttons' id='no'>No
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){ //shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#no').removeAttr("checked"); // selects id no and unchecks it
   $('#yes').attr('checked', true);  // selects id yes and checks it
});
```

EDIT:

Javascript

```
$(function(){
   // This will switch all radio buttons on the page, assuming you only have those 2.
   $radio_buttons = $('input:radio');
   $radio_buttons.each(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
         $(this).prop('checked', false);
      }
      else{
         $(this).prop('checked', true);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: the OP is talking about a plugin. It's unlikely he has direct access to the code other wise he could just add `checked="checked"` to the element and no js required

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply FERMIS.
There's only one problem. The plugin shortcode creates the radio buttons and it only gives each button a type, name, value and class, but no id.
Is there anyway to make this work with value instead of id?

Comment: Fair enough, I will try to revise my response then.

Comment: Are these the only radio buttons on the page?

Comment: Yes, these are the only 2 radio buttons on the page.

Comment: If you would like more details about what the jQuery is doing I can add more comments.

Comment: Thanks FERMIS for the effort. I'm curious to try the code, only dreamweaver gives a syntax error in this line: $radio-buttons = $('input:radio');

Comment: Try $radio_buttons = $('input:radio');

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question. Unfortunally the solution of FERMIS did not work for me. With a lot more searching i found something that not only works, bit uses the value of the radio button so should even work with more than 2 radio buttons. This is the code

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[value="Yes"]').attr('checked', 'checked');

Simple and short, but effective :)